# Twitter Stream API: Consume statuses from single user?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter stream API to listen to when a single user tweets but it is not working.  I am using the `twitter` library.  This is what I have:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXXX'
});

var stream = client.stream('statuses/filter', {follow: 123123});  // example user id placeholder

stream.on('data', function(event) {
  console.log(event && event.text);
});
```

When the account (123123) tweets I do not get anything in the stream.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the userId (`123123`) needs to be passed as a string (`'123123'`).